# Replacing an images with different file names with one image

Tags: file

I am working on a project and need to replace many images:

I have one image 1.png which needs to replace about 40 different png files with different names so 2.png, 3.png etc. What is important is that when 1.png replaces 2.png, 3.png etc. the file name does not change. In other words, the content of 1.png should replace the content of 2.png and 3.png, but it should not replace the file name.

I am not sure if this is possible, however, if it is I would be very happy to hear how.

Comment: What are you trying to ultimately achieve?  Why do you want 40 copies of the same image to be stored 40 times under 40 different names?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve this with powershell.

Something along these lines.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\source\folder' -Recurse
ForEach ($file In $files)
{
    Write-Host 'Replacing:'$file.FullName
    If ($file.Name -eq '2.png')
    {
        Copy-Item -Path 'c:\source\file\1.png' -Destination $file.FullName -Force
        Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName "2.png"
    }
}
```

Here is a link in case you haven't created a PS script before

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-and-run-your-first-powershell-script-file-windows-10